# Where to keep Redlaser License file in Titanium Alloy Project?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, barcode-scanner, titanium-alloy, license-key

In Titanium **Classic** project scanning worked fine when license file was kept in **Resources** folder along with **app.js** file.

Not sure where to keep the license file in Titanium **Alloy** project - gives me error that "**SDK Not Authorized**" You are over the scan limit for this device and application.

I have a paid license from RedLaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5222#!questions/question/2131) you have to put it in your app/assets folder since the assets replaced the classic resources folder.

Comment: I looked everywhere but the Appcelerator support. I tried your solution and it worked. Thank you so much!